# Limit of the series $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \csc\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Does the following limit exist?

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \csc\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)$$

I've computed the value for a few $n$ and it seems that the limit is zero. Any idea on how to prove this rigorously? The problem arises from electrostatics when computing the forces on point charges arranged in a ring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\sin(\pi x)\geq 2x$ for $x\in (0,1/2)$,
$$0\leq \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \csc\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)\leq \frac{2}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^{n/2} \csc\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)
\leq \frac{2}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^{n/2} \frac{1}{2\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)}\leq \frac{\ln(n+1)}{n\pi}$$
where we used the fact that $\sum_{k=1}^{n/2}\frac{1}{k}\leq \ln(n+1)$.

As $n\to +\infty$, the right-hand side goes to zero and therefore , by the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem#Statement), also the required limit is zero.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$ \csc\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right) = \frac{n}{k\pi}+O\left(\frac kn\right)$$

therefore

$$\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \csc\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right) =\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left(\frac{n}{k\pi}+O\left(\frac kn\right) \right)=$$

$$\frac{1}{\pi n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left(\frac{1}{k}\right)+\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}O\left(\frac kn\right) =\frac{\ln(n-1)}{\pi n}+O\left(\frac 1n\right) \to 0$$